# Promise resolve just for success?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I'm writing an simple REST API in JavaScript and i wonder whats the best approach when using Promises and resolving/rejecting mechanism.

At first i wanted to make promise signature like:

```
MyApi.getSomeData()
     .then(responseSuccess => console.log(responseSuccess))
     .catch(responseError => console.log(responseError)
```

where `success` means we got i.e. code `200` and have some data but error means i.e. we get `404` from server. I wanted to ensure that end user that will use the API methods will have guarantee the on error(catch) he'll get particular object.

But what if the promise throws some exception somewhere inside (some runtime error or some such)? Then the promise will be rejected with this `Error` instead of my responseError structure.

Whats the best approach in those cases? How to distinguish between operation success, operation failure (but intentionally, i.e. `404` code) and operation unexpected error?

Comment: `Whats the best approach in those cases?` - it really depends

Answer (score 0):

Run time errors in the promise will trigger the catch block. There is no avoiding that. You can however distinguish between runtime errors and network errors by checking the body of the error. So suppose

```
responseError = {
  type: 'NETWORK_ERROR', 
  status: 400, 
  message: 'Invalid input'
}

if (responseError.type === 'NETWORK_ERROR') {
  // Network error code here
} else {
  // All other types of errors
}
```

You can also abstract this logic in a common place so you can reuse it.

Comment: This is something i've been thinking about but i wanted to make it clean from usage perspective. So end user wont need to check the type of error in catch block. Maybe if promises had `.then().catch().exception()` type it would be simpler.

Comment: No real way to avoid type checking as we have only 2 output types (`then` and `catch`) and 3 cases (`success`, `failure`, `runtime execption`)